# UrlLib2 - Access denied while requesting ASP.NET website on workplace network

Tags: python, asp.net, security, urllib2, sessionid

I am currently writing a script which involves (hopefully) screen scraping a lot of data from an webpage that is for my workplace. It is an ASP.NET page, and requires no login at all when viewing it on Chrome or Internet Explorer.

I have tried "session jacking" my internet explorer session in order to get it read by URLLIB2 in Python, but I still get access denied (after adding the ASP.NET_Sessionid that internet explorer is using...)

I admittedly know very little about internet networking, so I'm probably doing something wrong here, but I need to access this webpage from Python. I'm willing to use another Library if it works better.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the webpage is checking for valid request headers?

You really should use pycurl for this type of jobs.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pycurl
import cStringIO
buf = cStringIO.StringIO()

pycurl_headers = ['Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                  'Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
                  'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,bg;q=0.6',
                  'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 \
                  (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31']


c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://google.com')
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buf.write)
c.setopt(c.AUTOREFERER, 1)
c.setopt(c.FOLLOWLOCATION , True)
c.setopt(c.CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5)
c.setopt(c.TIMEOUT, 5)
c.setopt(c.HTTPHEADER, pycurl_headers)
c.perform()

print buf.getvalue()
buf.close()
```

Comment: Already tried that... Copied the exact header data from my google chrome session (while it was requesting the webpage I'm attempting to parse) and am using it in my URLLIB2 requests... I'm even sending the session cookie in the header as well... I don't know what data I could possibly be leaking that's telling the server I'm not a browser?

Comment: Please try my code and then write again. My code sends referrer and catches redirects.